# Regular expression help - ignoring parenthesis, ands, ors and whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

Given this:
(C AND (D OR    B))
how can I return a collection of items: C,B,D 
while ignoring AND, OR, whitespace and parenthesis?
Sorry if the question is too silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split the string.

```
string[] items = "(C AND (D OR B))".Split(new[] { "(", ")", "AND", "OR", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace all the unwanted `AND`, `OR`, `(`, `)` from the string with `space`.

```
string input = "(C AND (D OR B))";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"AND|OR|[)(]", " ");
```

Then trim the string. and replace consecutive spaces with comma(`,`):

```
input = Regex.Replace(input.Trim(), @"[ ]+", ",");
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you want a collection as in an array instead of a comma-delimited string, you could `split()` the string after the replacement.